# Xcode Version 11.0 (11A420a) (.presentation) deprecate?

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

I have this script:

```
List {

        //code

    }.presenation($displayAlert) {
        Alert(title: Text("Start1"), message: Text("other...."), dismissButton: .default(Text("Go!")))
    }
```

I receive error:

> "Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'View' because only concrete types can conform to protocols"

I think that the .presentation is deprecate on Version 11.0 (11A420a)

How can I fix this error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show an alert you need to use the `.alert` modifier as the `.presentation` modifier was deprecated in Beta 4.

Here is a quick example showing how to use it.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showAlert = false

    var body: some View {

        List {

            Button(action: {
                self.showAlert.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("press me")
            }

        }.alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Title"), message: Text("Message"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK!")))
        }
    }
}
```

You may also want to consider updating your version of Xcode as 11.2 was released today